# Obfuscate email adress and password devise rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

Using Devise for Authentication

I want to Obfuscate user information like username and password when request comes from the client side

```
<%= bootstrap_form_for(resource, as: resource_name, url: session_path(resource_name, service: params[:service]), html: { class: 'm-t' }) do |f| %>

  <%= devise_error_messages! %>

  <%= f.email_field :name, required: true, hide_label: true, placeholder: 'Name' %>
  <%= f.password_field :password, required: true, hide_label: true, placeholder: 'Password'%>

  <%= f.submit "Sign In", class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block dark-button-text' %>

<% end %>
```

The name and password in the request body are visible which should be encrypted, i am trying to use javascript

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('form#new_user').submit(function() {
      let userPassword = $('#user_password')
      let userName = $('#user_name')
      userPassword.val(window.btoa(userPassword.val()))
      userName.val(window.btoa(userName.val()))
    })
  })
```

But this updating value on the browser.

On application how to decrypt the same as devise session controller is doing sanitizing of the incoming request.

Comment: The default behavior of the password field is to show bullets instead of characters. Is it not what you get from your above HTML ?

Comment: ON Html we can see the bullets but when request is submitted i want encrypted password to go.

Comment: Why do you want it encrypted ? If you have an SSL certificate it will be encrypted across the internet.

Comment: Found the solution